# How to output analysis progress into console

Tags: r

How can write an R code for console output of the progress of my analysis?

I have the following code for looping over several folders:

```
for (f in folder.paths){
cmd....
}
```

I want the following message to be outputted in the console: "Running folder Sky1...."

Thanks

Comment: You need to accept an asnwer to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Fernando's answer, but here everything stays on the same line:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  cat("\rWorking on", i)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Try it out.

Answer (score 3):

`message()` might be another alternative to `cat`. The help (`?message`) says:

> `message` is used for generating ‘simple’ diagnostic messages which are
>   neither warnings nor errors, but nevertheless represented as
>   conditions. Unlike warnings and errors, a final newline is regarded as
>   part of the message, and is optional.

Comment: I think it's much better solution than `cat`, simple use for OP: `message( "Running folder ", f)`. Once in function it could be hidden by `suppresMessages` (do it for `cat` ;)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use cat():

```
n.files = length(folder.paths)

for (i in 1 : n.files){
    cat("proc: ", round(100*i/n.files, 1), "%", sep = "",  "\n")
}
```

Not tested, but it should work.

Comment: Can also use something like `if( i%%10==0 )  cat(...)` if you want every 10th line to print out.

Comment: Thank you for your help. All solutions worked for me. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user27976 Please click the check mark next to the answer you think best solved your problem.  That helps keep track of which questions still are unresolved, and nets the best answerer some points (you get a few as well!).

Comment: Apologies for getting back late! Thanks to everyone. I have found bits of most codes and comments useful. The problem is now solved. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use a logging package, such as `logging` or `futile.logger`.

Why?

Well, you can define messages with different 'levels' - info, warning, etc - and then globally control whether you see those messages. So you (or whoever is running your code) has the power to not see the messages if they don't want. You might even be able to define different loggers for different functions, so you can turn off messages from a particular function without having to go in and comment them out or include some kludgy `if(loggingthis)cat("here we are\n")` code. You might even be able to direct log messages to files instead of the console.

**OR**

If you want to show *progress*, use a *progress bar*! There's `txtProgressBar` in base R, and the `plyr` package has some fancier ones. Just install `plyr` and do `help.search("progress")`